# Admins, staff, and ? users of a website

Tags: word-request, terminology, internet

The word "admin" refers to somebody who can do everything at our site, "staff" refers to staff of our company which are not necessarily admins.

We sell services (parts of our site) to organizations.

Then how to call a user who controls an organization (and is not our staff member)? This person is usually the CEO of our customer company or a head of their IT department.

Comment: Moderator? or maybe a side-admin?

Comment: @SovereignSun moderator is for somebody filters messages of other users, we have no such function. Regarding "side-admin", please explain meaning, etymology, and usage of this weird phrase

Comment: **Side** has a meaning **subsidiary** which means **less important than but related or supplementary to something**. Example: Side job, side worker.

Comment: @SovereignSun The distinction is mainly not by importance but by the fact that "admins" and "staff" are staff of our company, but these who I ask about how to name them are people belonging to a customer company

Comment: Community Members?

Comment: @Davo I ask about users *with increased rights inside their company's section of our site*, not "community members"

Comment: Outside admin maybe?

Comment: @SovereignSun Maybe, but this phrase "outside admin" seems weird for me and may cause some confusion, as it looks like to imply that outside admins are admins

Comment: They aren't remote ones ))) What about Third-party admins?

Comment: Maybe "admins from outside (third-party) organizations"?

Comment: @SovereignSun "Third-party admins" is better but not perfect, because third-party usually refers to an organization which is not in our contract. They are actually "second-party" admins because they are our customers. But the phrase "second-party" seems not to be widespread enough

Comment: Maybe "customer admins"? But I prefer to name it by one short word. Maybe "managers"?

Comment: Then why not Zone Admin and Zone Staff, to mirror the site-wide nomenclature while indicating that these roles are restricted to certain local zones?

Comment: What's their role on the website? If technically there's no difference between a CEO and a visitor then both are simply users. Otherwise you should define them like "Customer CEO", "Customer Admin", "Customer Staff", etc.

Answer (score 1):

I offer **Zone Admin** and **Zone Staff**, to mirror the site-wide nomenclature while indicating that these roles are restricted to (a) certain local zone(s).